# is there a max_value function for xml child node?

Tags: php, xml

thanks you all for helping me to learn xml+php!

I want to make an Autoincrement for the id child node.
in my createxml.php i'm the one who enter the id..
i want to be able to know what is the maxium value of all id's and then the **id=max_value++**

I hope i explain my self well.

**this is the events.xml file:**

```
<events>
    <record>
        <id>1</id>
        <event>a</event>
        <eventDate>a</eventDate>
        <desc>a</desc>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>2</id>
        <event>b</event>
        <eventDate>b</eventDate>
        <desc>b</desc>
    </record>
</events>
```

**and this is how i adding new child nodes to the xml..**

**parser.php:**

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$record = array(
    'id' => $_POST['id'],
    'event' => $_POST['event'],
    'eventDate' => $_POST['eventDate'],
    'desc' => $_POST['desc'],
);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'events.xml' );
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$r = $doc->getElementsByTagName("events")->item(0);
$b = $doc->createElement("record");

$id = $doc->createElement("id");
$id->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["id"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $id );

$event = $doc->createElement("event");
$event->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["event"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $event );

$eventDate = $doc->createElement("eventDate");
$eventDate->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["eventDate"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $eventDate );

$desc = $doc->createElement("desc");
$desc->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["desc"] )
);

$b->appendChild( $desc );
$r->insertBefore( $b,$r->firstChild );

$doc->save("events.xml");

    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");    
?>
```

**Thanks all for helping!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
$ids = array();
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('id') as $id) {
    $ids[] = (int) $id->nodeValue;
}
$max_id = max($ids);
```

---

**Edit** Possibly a nicer way is with XPath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$max_id = $xpath->query('//events/record[not(../record/id > id)]/id')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: If you're already looping over the items, you may as well bubble sort it yourself.

Comment: Thanks mate! this is perfect!, well i wanted to make it that the new one will be shown at top.. so i don't need the bubble.. but thanks you very much! that was helpful!

Comment: do you know how i'm making $max_id to a string?

Comment: @Ofear Just treat it as one...  See also my updated answer, with an XPath version.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool for finding the max id is [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).  If you were using a [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/simplexml) object and the records were known to be in order by id, then getting the id would go something like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$xpath="(//record@id)[last()]";
$lastid=$xml->xpath($xpath);
```

If your results are unordered, then the XPath expression can get a bit hairy, but it's still likely to be a lot faster than looping through the results.